# Siri spells my child’s name wrong in texts

Tags: ios, contacts, siri, voice-dictation

Siri spells my child’s name wrong in texts. I tried all the suggestions given on here and it didn’t work. Added the field ‘phonetic spelling’ and spelled it the way Siri is spelling it. Then added the field “nickname”. When neither of those worked, I tried putting quotes around the correct spelling of the name. None of these worked. I just got an Xr. I even tapped on ‘tap to edit’and changed it but that didn’t work either.

Comment: I get if you don’t want to name names on the internet, but this would be something to get Apple support on the line so they can know what specific name pattern isn't’ working and validate you entered the name correctly in contacts app. Once you favorite that contact, Siri should prefer the spelling and learn how to spell and pronounce family members.

Comment: It just worked! Just took awhile to register the change I guess.

Comment: Yay Debi! Please put in an answer and I’ll vote

Comment: I did not have your luck. My daughter's name is Cori. NOTHING WORKS. I did everything, like Debi. And my daughter has always been a contact, a Favorite, and an Emergency contact. I made sure there is no Corey in my phone. I texted 20 texts to myself with her name and corrected it. The best I get is Corey with the blue line under it to enable me to correct to Cori. OR sometimes it will spell her name correctly, "Cori went to Julia's house" but when I click the keyboard symbol to get out of dictation, it GOES BACK to the incorrect spelling. I'm about to pull my hair out. Did phonetic, nickname,

Answer (score 3):

If a person is a contact and Siri doesn’t pronounce it correctly, you can ask Siri to show you their contact. After  she shows it to you, you can say “that’s not how you say that”, and Siri should ask you how to pronounce it.

Comment: This answer does not seem to answer the question asked.

Answer (score -2):

Someone here said something about pronunciation, I guess they didn’t read the original question. Several people here had the same question that I and maybe millions more half, but we’re ignored by Apple. The problem is, that Siri has only one way of spelling, a name, and we don’t have a method (that I know of) to force her to spell it as we wish.
Guys, spelling is not the same thing as pronunciation…

Comment: Correcting Siri’s pronunciation of the contact seems to make it easier to get the spelling to be correct. Especially since Siri is listening to us speak the word, and then transcribing it based on the language model and the hints based on contacts database and other corrections when you go in and fix what Siri has typed. Please consider editing this to explain in a little how you’re able to be sure the two concepts aren’t linked